# How to disallow to input minus sign(-) in jQuery Inputmask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, masking, input-mask

this is my first entry in here, hope that I won't fail some rules.

I have an input field in HTML file that takes Port numbers from 0 to 65535 which is defined as min, max.

And I have a jQuery Input mask in JS file that is supposed to allow only inputs.

ACTUALLY, it works as it is supposed to in my local, but when I upload the code to the environment, there you can enter tons of minus(-) sign.

Well, I have compared the versions of jQuery and mask of my local and the server and I made them the same but it didn't help me to fix the problem.

JS:

```
$('#input_port').mask('00000', {
  placeholder: "Enter between 0-65535"
});
```

My expectation is that the code should allow entering ONLY numbers from 0 to 65535 but it allows you to enter more number after minus sign such as 65535------12345 but it should not.

Comment: If it works locally with the same set of files look in the browsers error console, likely you will see an issue with a script path.

Comment: I can't work out what library you are using. The obvious one is throwing `mask is not a function` when I try it. Please provide an [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the editor.

Comment: 1. please provide details regarding which plugin you are using.  2 if it's working differently in local-vs-prd, then check what's different.  Different browser?  Local using `file:`?  Use the browser's network tab to determine *exactly* which .js files are being included - you can see the file in the network tab then open in a new tab from there to view it.  Maybe a different CDN giving a different file.  Are you using any sort of min'd files?  These *can* be different (for the same version) - try using un-min'd versions to get it to work first. Control-F5 both to ensure no cached files.

Comment: @Quentin and freedom you guys are right, sorry.. 
Libraries in my local are listed below, https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js
I already added them to Prod locally. So, these are the same.. Browser is the same.. I have also tried Control-F5 but I did not try that un-min'd versions, thanks for the advice guys! I hope I will be giving feedback that I solved the issue thanks to you guys!

Comment: @AlexK. Hi sir, as you mentioned I pressed F12 to see browsers error console and I received 4 formats of this: 

jquery.min.js:2 GET https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&rnd=2019449&diagnostics=true&callback=jQuery34103836174067783187_1559199347917&q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%22New%20York%20City%22)%20and%20u=%22f%22&_=1559199347918 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED